# What is the difference between calling "id -G" and "id -G -r"?

Tags: shell, group, coreutils

I know the `-r` flag should print the real group the user is in. But since `-G` already prints all his groups, does this make a difference?

What does `id -gr xxxsome_user` really print out? How can a user have a real group? I thought only process could have effective and real groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the -r flag should print the real group the user is in. But since -G already prints all his groups, does this make a difference?

No.

> What does id -gr xxxsome_user really print out? How can a user have a real group? I thought only process could have effective and real groups.

That's right. The susv4 [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/id.html) is a bit more explicit than the linux manpage:

> ```
>  If a user operand is provided and the process has appropriate
>  privileges, the user and group IDs of the selected user shall be
>  written. In this case, effective IDs shall be assumed to be
>  identical to real IDs.
> ```